# Is there a nice form for the Frobenius characteristic of a border shape character?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-combinatorics

Let $\chi^V$ be the character of a border strip Specht module, i.e. a Specht 
module for a skew tableau that contains no $2 \times 2$ square. I know that
the Frobenius characteristic of $\chi^V$ is the skew-Schur function $s_{V}$.
I then tried to express this skew Schur function as a product of complete 
homogeneous polynomials $h_i$ using the Jacobi-Trudi identity. It turns out 
that the matrix is nearly upper triangular, but there is a sub-diagonal of 
$1$'s. Is there a combinatorial interpretation for the expansion of the 
Frobenius characteristic of $\chi^V$ in terms of the $h_i$? Is there a nice
closed form? It seems like the Jacobi-Trudi determinant has a lot of
patterns ... .

Comment: You know there is the Murnaghan-Nakaygma rule for skew shapes?
www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/transparencies/bstrip.ps

Comment: Thank you! I think I did run across the Murnaghan-Nakaygma rule for skew shapes, but I never thought to use it here. I will give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

The determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix with a subdiagonal of 1's, and
0's below the 1's, can be written as a sum over subsets of $S$ and interpreted
in terms of Inclusion-Exclusion. See *Enumerative Combinatorics*,
vol. 1, second ed., Example 2.2.4. In fact, the determinant (2.16) of
this example is the "exponential specialization" of the Jacobi-Trudi
determinant of a border strip Schur function. Thus one gets a formula
for $s_V$ as a sum over subsets of a set, and this formula can be
proved by a direct Inclusion-Exclusion argument.  I don't think there
is a simpler explicit formula. In volume 2, Cor. 7.23.5, there is a
generating function for the $s_V$'s which is sometimes useful.